# Azure error AADSTS50020 while loggin in from VS2022

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

AADSTS50020: User account 'my@email' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/783c0fcf-4d70-4426-9bbc-1e83f8b865b2/' does not exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and cannot access the application '872cd9fa-d31f-45e0-9eab-6e460a02d1f1'(Visual Studio).
I am logging in with an account (mine) that is a Global Administrator and owner of that Azure organization. How can I be not authorized? This makes zero sense -__- As a test I invited my other email (on a different domain) as an external guest and the login worked for that account. So I can login as a guest but not as an owner.

Answer (score 1):

There maybe relatably few possible causes for this error.

```
Possible cause 1
```

- Please check if you might have  already have an active session that
  uses a different account  (personal) than the one that's intended to
  be used where you are admin. Or  it maybe meant for guest user
  account.
- To see if above is the reason, look for the User account and Identity
  provider values in the error message. Check if those values match the
  expected combination .
- See if sign in is done by using organization account to your tenant
  instead of  home tenant Or is the login is by using a different
  personal account than the one that needed to be.

  **Resolution**

To resolve this issue please sign out from active session, then sign in again from a different browser or a private browser session.

```
Cause 2
```

- Also if you have set Supported account types to Multiple
  organizations. But if your authentication call is for specific tenant
  i.e., https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant name or id. In that
  case users from other organizations cannot  be able to access the
  application and those users are required to be added as guests in the
  tenant specified in the request.Maybe this seems to be the reason for
  as guest account is signed in.

  **Resolution**
- So for multiple organizations, authentication request should either
  be common or organizations ex:
  [https://login.microsoftonline.com/`organizations`](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%60organizations%60) or
  [https://login.microsoftonline.com/`common`](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%60common%60)

Also check [Error AADSTS50020 - User account from identity provider does not exist in tenant - Active Directory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist?msclkid=ce865af7cc3f11ecb681eb3c54ebc1e1) to troubleshoot in other cases.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to "Sigh-out" in the tiny sign-in window popup by Visual Studio 2022. What else I can do?